# Downconverting UVC from a merucry lamp (255nm) to UVB broadband?

Tags: optics

I would like to take light from a UVC lamp (~255nm) and downconvert it to a broadband from 200nm to 400nm. How could I do this?

If I wanted to develop my own materials or source them, what elements would be a good place to start looking?

Answer (score 1):

As you say the source is a UV lamp I’m going to rule out [spontaneous parametric down conversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion)  and suggest that you consider using **down-shifting** instead.

Down-shifting uses a [luminophore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminophore) to absorb light of high energy and emit it at a lower energy: [fluorescence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence).

You could use inexpensive plastic sheets doped with a fluorescent dye.

[image: plastic sheet]

**You will need to find an dye which has the correct characteristics for your purpose.**

You didn’t mention anything about performance or details of your setup, so I’ve listed some potential problems,

- At the wavelength of 255nm it’s going to be hard to cut out parasitic absorption from glass and plastics. I believe the absorption peak at ~250nm in the plot below is from the acetone rather than the dye.
- Your beam will be lost and replaced with Lambertian emission from the sheet edges

I have some experience with [Lumogen F Violet 570](http://www2.basf.us/additives/pdfs/lumvio570.pdf), this will convert high energy photons to emission in the range 350nm to 550nm.

[image: Lumogen dye]

It does not seem ideal of your purpose. But it is readily available in inexpensive fluorescent sheets you can buy online.

Another option is to use a nanocrystals but that’s becoming a bit specialist. Start-ups are using this technology to make “[power from glass](https://www.glasstopower.com/?lang=en)”.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a fluorescence in the 200-400nm range. Is there a luminophore that fluoresces in that range?

Comment: Personally I only have experience with visible dyes. There does seem to be interest in this in the past to make UV lasers https://www.osapublishing.org/abstract.cfm?uri=CLEO-1986-THI6